# How to execute stored procedure on click Html button?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I need to execute stored procedure which is on database, to on click Html button!!

**name of stored procedure:** `DeleteRow`

```
    <form action="">
    <input type="button" value="Check" onclick="">
    </form>
```

How I can execute using php?? Is it possible?

** SQL query:**

```
CALL `DeleteRow`();
```

Comment: Either submit a form or make an Ajax request which then runs some PHP on the server which calls the procedure. Standard web application structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<input type='button' value='Call Procedure' id='BtnId'>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#BtnId").on( 'click', function(){

        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "callsp.php",
            success : function(text){
                alert(text);
            }
        });

        return false;
    }); 

});
```

**PHP:** *(callsp.php)*

```
<?php

// connect to database
$connection = mysqli_connect("hostname", "username", "password", "db", "port");

// run the query
$result = mysqli_query($connection, "CALL DeleteRow");

// loop the result set
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) {
  print_r( $row );
}

?>
```

Comment: @Naveed Bro I don't want alert while clicking button can we disable or remove Alert window??

Comment: Yes.  Remove **alert(text);** from jQuery part.

Answer (score -1):

Let's say you have  stored procedure something like

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE getDetails()
BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM tablename;
END$$
```

Now you can execute this in the following way in `PHP`

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
// execute the stored procedure
$sql = 'CALL getDetails()';
// call the stored procedure
$q = $pdo->query($sql);
$q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

while ($r = $q->fetch()){
  /*
  * Do something
  */
}
```

On click, you can implement Ajax to make it work. You can follow [PHP Ajax Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php)